# C# ASP.NET Post Back Data

Tags: asp.net, webforms, textbox, postback

I have a web page form which contains around 20 forms(home.aspx), on 1 of it i need to put a link beside a textbox which will be pop out when the user clicks the link(search.aspx). In this pop out link there will be a search textbox which will search the database based on the keyword that user enters. Let's say the user enters id number (1111) and the result shown will be the name of the ID 1111. The question is when the user clicks on the row of the result it will be automatically back into home.aspx and the selected name is placed in the textbox?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a [cross page postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) from your search.aspx to your home.aspx. I'd consider putting the search in the page though. Why not just have the search box appear in your main form when you click on the link (make it a link button rather than a link).